# How to implement razor.cshtml file within action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to implement view.cshtml file within action and then get its result as string, but not returning as ActionResult from action method.
To explain with code, instead of:

```
public ActionResult Tesst()
        {
            // return ViewResult
            return View();
        }
```

İt must be so:

```
public string Test()
        {
            string viewResult = string.Empty;
            // implement "test.cshtml" and get its result as string
            // assign result to viewResult variable
            return viewResult;
        }
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering what are you trying to achieve - there might be a cleaner solution to your problem.

Comment: This question looks like it will provide you the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this to render a view inside my app to a string:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller,
                                  string viewName, string layout, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult =
                   ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(
                           controller.ControllerContext, viewName, layout);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                   controller.ControllerContext, 
                   viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, 
                   controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, does all codeside work properly? Such as @{ ... } or @Datetime.Now